# jquery sends post data but no response

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog containing a form with the name and id of 'buildtask'. Looking at it with Firebug it is fully formed. The jquery code is identical to other successful dialog form submissions on the same page.
The problem seems to be with the `$(this).dialog("close");` because if I comment that out, the called ajax php script works to update the database and echo a piece of text that I can see via Firebug. Of course the dialog stays on screen.

With the commenting out removed, the database update fails and while the post data shows in Firebug, the response tab is missing and it shows the size as 0B.

I tried moving the  `$(this).dialog("close");` within the `function(data){ }` but it leaves the dialog on screen.

I have scoured Stackoverflow with every combination of the question but no joy and I have been messing with this for over six hours.

```
    buttons: {
                "Update": function() {$.post("ajax/udTManage.php", $("#buildtask").serialize(),function(data){alert("Here");});
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                }
            },
            close: function() {
                $("#buildtask").remove();                       
                $('#tasker').submit();

            }
```

Comment: Are any errors showing up in the error tab of firebug?

Comment: There were no errors showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `$( this ).dialog( "close" );` into the `function(data){}` to make sure the form is not dismissed before you finish sending the request.

Althought, since the event is fired by the AJAX call, using `$( this )` refers to the request and not the dialog.

Thus you should call the window by it's id and do something like this : `$("#buildtask").dialog("close");`

Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks That did it - actually it was another id - the one of the containing div that I loaded the original ajax-derived form into which was needed. It sorted the timing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the code in your close function will be executed the moment you click Update or Cancel. If you click Update, #buildtask is removed and #tasker is submitted while udTManage.php is still being executed.

Without knowing your process it's hard to determine where it's failing, but one guess is that whatever is happening in udTManage.php needs to be completed before #tasker is submitted. Is that the case? If so, the following should solve the problem:

```
buttons: {
    "Update": function() {
        $.post(
            "ajax/udTManage.php",
            $("buildtask").serialize(),
            function(data) {
                // anything here is executed AFTER udTManage.php is executed
                $('#tasker').submit();
            }
        );
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "Cancel": function() {
        $("tasker").submit(); // assuming you need to submit even when cancelling
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
},
close: function() {
    // This is executed the moment you click either button (because both buttons immediately call the dialog close method)
    $("buildtask").remove(); // not sure why you might need this, though
}
```

Comment: The remove in the close is to clear the form - otherwise the values can persist into the next use. You are right that the submit in  the Cancel is not needed - It was just part of the testing to check the host page was being refreshed to reflect the item had been dealt with.